# reading from an InputStream

Tags: android, sockets, inputstream, latitude-longitude

I have an client server application on Android.And I have to send data from client to server.
The data that I send is GPS data wrapped this way:

```
GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(latitude,longitude);
geoPointsArray.add(p);
```

Now,everything goes fine...I succed to send the data through the socket,but at the server I have to take all this data and write it in a database.

The way that I read the data at the server is this:

```
BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
String line=null;
while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
}
```

Now in `line = in.readLine()`, I have a line of GPS data (latitude,longitude) and I can't figure out how could I read (latitude,longitude) of a point, wrap it back in a geopoint p...after that read another (latitude,longitude) put it in "geopoint p" and so on....And after that to write "geopoint p" in a database!

P.S:What I don't understand is how to read from that "line" so that I put the correct latitude and longitude of a point together on the database.

Hope I've been clear enough.I'm here for further details.Thank u in advance!

Comment: How do you send the data to the server? Plain Text?

Comment: PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
      out.println(p);...and p is the geopoint as I explained on my post.If u have any ideas about how to send it in a different way I'm all eyes and ears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can send the Lat/Lon information on a Simple text manner and in the server side do a very simple parsing. This would be quick and easy to do. So, instead of sending an direct GeoPoint object send the info inside of it written plainly and read it the other side of the pipe. Sounds good?

JQCorreia

Comment: Yes,this would be simple and sounds good,but there is a problem.My client is the one who stores gps data coming from a car,let say.And at the server I have to store that data,but in the same time the server should do also real time tracking(I mean to locate the sorce of gps data)...Now if I send the data in a file I'll have to wait until all the data is written in the file(that means the source of gps data has stopped  )...and I can't do any real time tracking.

Comment: Don't send it in a file, send it through the stream but instead of sending a data object that you can't decode in the other side(i suppose this is the original issue), do it in a manner that you CAN decode :)